# Esper UpdateListener's concurrency

Tags: multithreading, concurrency, esper

My boss want to me learning Esper, the open source library for CEP, so I need some help.

I want to many UpdateListener subscribing one event stream, and they run on concurrently. That means, if one listener have a long and big process, then other listener running concurrency, because we have so many event at short time, so I need more fast processing.

Answer (score 0):

The UpdateListener code can simply use a Java threadpool to do its work. For an example there is http://www.javacodegeeks.com/2013/01/java-thread-pool-example-using-executors-and-threadpoolexecutor.html.
In Esper you can also configure threading.
http://esper.codehaus.org/esper-5.1.0/doc/reference/en-US/html_single/index.html#api-threading-advanced

Comment: Thanks for Ur Tip! I'll try this at my work. And.... anyone has some tip, I want to more that, plz.